# Does nextjs build components that are not reachable by env var?

Tags: typescript, next.js

let's say we have the following code:

```js
import PageA from './PageA'
import PageB from './PageB'

export default function BranchPage(){
  // suppose process.env.CURRENT_PAGE is 'a'
  return process.env.CURRENT_PAGE === 'a' ? <PageA/> : <PageB/>
}
```

if environment variable `process.env.CURRENT_PAGE` is `a` at build time, this means that `PageB` component is unreachable. Does nextjs bulid `PageB` and check lint with typescript even in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same as:

```
let input = 4;
if (input < 5){
   console.log("<5")
}
else {
 console.log(">= 5")
}
```

Will compiler pre-"console" else? No, the same principle nextjs has.

P.S. If you speaking about `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` - your condition will be taken according to the moment of build